# Unable to access a method's local variables outside of the method in Java

Tags: java, variables, methods, scope

I am new to Java and am trying to access method variables outside of the method, but it doesn't work.

Code is below:

```java
public class MethodAccess {
    public static void minus() {
        int a=10;
        int b=15;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Here i want to access variable names a & b that is in minus()
        int c = b - a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well no, it wouldn't. Local variables (declared within a method) only exist for the lifetime of that method call, within the method. You need to declare fields, by the sounds of it.

Comment: Yes, those are *local variables* and they are not visible outside of their scope. You need to structure your code in a different way.

Comment: And by the way, it is somewhat conventional to begin a class name with a capital (and maybe use camel case), so your class name should be MethodAccess....but just as a note : )

Answer (score 4):

Because `a` and `b` are local variables.
If you want to access to them in your main method, you need to modify your code. For example :

```
public class methodacess {
       private static int a;
       private static int b;

       public static void minus(){   
           methodacess obj =new methodacess();
           a=10;
           b=15;    
       }   

       public static void main (String[] args){     
           int c = b - a;    
       }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The variables that are defined inside a method are local to that method, so you cannot use them outside. If you want to use them outside, define instance variables in the beginning of your class.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to do it hte other way around:

```
public class methodacess {

     public int minus(int a, int b){   
          int c = b - a;
          return c;
     }   
     public static void main (String[] args){   
          // Here youi want to call minus(10, 15) 
          int a=10;
          int b=15;
          System.out.println("Result is: " + minus(a, b))
     }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the variables as static class variables, so you can access them from a static function. Also watch out for the access modifiers, since when the variable is private you can't access them outside any other class.

```
public class methodacess {

   private static int a;
   private static int b;

   public static void minus(){   
      methodacess obj =new methodacess();
      a=10;
      b=15;
   }  

   public static void main (String[] args){   
      //Here i want to access variable names a & b that is in minus() 
      int c = b - a; 
   }   

}
```